# sendOrderedBroadcast resultReceiver handler

Tags: android, handler, broadcast

I am using sendOrderedBroadcast to collect some data.
In resultReceiver I parse this data, but this operation can take couple of seconds.

Now sendOrderedBroadcast has this "Handler scheduler" parameter which seems to be what I need, but unfortunately I don't really know how to use it. What I need is to process resultReceiver on a different thread. How to do that?

EDIT:
To rephrase the problem: In a broadcast receiver I need to parse a lot of data, construct View objects and add them to ArrayList. This blocks user interface. How can I do this without blocking UI? ...I can create new thread, but I can't create View objects from there...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you rather have to review your design.

The construction of view objects anyway needs to be done on the UI. The amount of heavy lifting to be done there depends on how you design the data to be available at the point of view construction.

You can spawn an `AsyncTask` which will do the parsing of data, when you receive your result. Return another list of objects from it which is probably a stripped down version (DTO) which will have properties needed for you to create your view objects. Do not write your parse logic inside the getters. Keep them simple. It will help to reduce the time which it blocks the UI.